# Screentime does not allow to set user that limits apply for

Tags: macos, screen-time

[image]Per this
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210387#limitusage
I should be able to select a user to change screen time limits for.

But I do not have other users on the mac listed in the top left corner.
There is no switch allowing to choose user limits apply for.

Ideas?

Comment: Have you set up family sharing?

Comment: I didn't. It wants a credit card. The accound is setup for US app store. I no longer have a US credit card to feed it and it's timeconsuming to call apple to change store to the current country of residence. There is no way around this aside from setting family sharing.

Comment: I've filed  FB9071215 with Apple. In my opinion this should not be tethered to family sharing.